# String placeholders {0} in masterpage URL's

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage, boot-strap

I'm working with the [bootstrap for sharepoint project](https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/) which includes some masterpages and page layouts to help make SP responsive.

While in the masterpage, on the left nav (quick launch) bar, I see links like the following

```
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/{0}/viewlsts.aspx" ID="idNavLinkSiteHierarchyV4" />
```

The string place holder `{0}` isn't getting replaced and throwing an error. Obviously, I can simply replace with `/_layouts/15/` and it will work but I've never seen string placeholders in a masterpage like this. Is there a reason to use these? And likewise make them render out the URL correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the {0} and replace it by /_layouts/15/
I'm also working with a Bootstrap masterpage and this is what I have in my master

```
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" id="idNavLinkSiteHierarchyV4" Text="<%$Resources:wss,treeview_header%>" accesskey="%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>" CssClass="ms-tv-header" />
```

If you want to test other master pages this is the free project that I'm using 
[Bootstrap 3 Theme SP2013](http://bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/theme/TheBootstrapTheme)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. I guess I was looking more for the "why" because I've never seen this done before and the project authors obviously put it in there for a reason.